# MySQLi get connection information from object

Tags: php, object, mysqli

How would I get the connection info from an instance of `$obj = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db)` function or from the mysql constructor `$obj = new mysql($host, $user, $pass, $db)`.

I have this class which will make MySQLi safer and easier to use.
But in the class I want an import MySQLi Object directrly into the class, but if I want to verify the connection I must have the connection details.

Everything in my class that you need to know looks like this:

```
 <?php
  class emsqli
  {
    private $con;  // Connection will be assigned to this variable

    public  $host; // Connection (Host)
    public  $user; // Connection (Username)
    private $pass; // Connection (Password)
    public  $db;   // Connection (Database)

    private function getConnectionInformation(object $con){
      // What to do here?
      // I need the host, user, pass and db.

      // The code below does not work, but this is something I had in mind
      $this->host = $con->host;
      $this->user = $con->user;
      $this->pass = $con->pass;
      $this->db   = $con->db;

      return true;
    }
  }
?>
```

**Why verify**?

```
<?php
    class emsql
    {
        public  $con;
        public  $host;
        public  $user;
        private $pass;
        public  $db;
        public  $connect_error;
        public  $connect_error_code;
        public  $connect_error_msg;
        public  $is_db_connected = false;
        public  $is_se_connected = false;

        public function reset(){
            $this->con = '';
            $this->host = '';
            $this->user = '';
            $this->pass = '';
            $this->db = '';
            $this->connect_error = '';
            $this->connect_error_code = '';
            $this->connect_error_msg = '';
            $this->is_db_connected = false;
            $this->is_se_connected = false;
        }



        public function import(object $mysqli){
            if(!is_object($mysqli) || !get_class($mysqli) == 'mysqli'){
                return false; // Not MySQLi object
            }
            else
            {
                if($mysqli->connect_errno){
                    return false; // Invalid object
                }

                $this->reset();
                $this->con = $mysqli;
                $this->is_se_connected = true;

                // Check if $mysqli has selected database
                if( !has_db($mysqli) ){ // This code does not work, but this is one thing I need to do
                    $this->is_db_connected = true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is that "verification" you are talking about? any reason to "verify the connection"?

Comment: Let me suggest you my article, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes). It's based on PDO, but the principle is the same. It may help you to avoid some fatal design flaws.

Comment: Ill have a look @YourCommonSense, thanks!

Comment: @YourCommonSense I really found your `run` function useful, thanks! Though it does not cover my problem, eventually something will work out.

Comment: Wait, this run() method is just a syntax sugar for running a prepared statement. I don't see how it's applicable for your case/ But well I asked too much questions already :)

Comment: I just got a few ideas from it, nothing else. Thanks for the article.

Answer (score 0):

Although there could be some tricky ways to get host, username and db, but obviously, there is no way to get the password.

Besides, I fail to see *any* use for these parameters if you already have the working connection.

Comment: It is not that I have a working connection, I am trying to make an clean import function to my Easy MySQLi class in php, but in order to verify the object, connection, database connected I will need to pull out username and password. But if this is not possible I will forget about that function

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you want to verify? In my own class I am just getting the mysqli object, and don't care for the password at all.

Comment: Basically there will be an import function which is supposed to import an instance of an MySQLi object, and in order to check that the connections is valid I need to make a new connection with the same details.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand, neither what the import is (what do we import and why?) nor why do you want to create another connection. For me, you need either credentials (and create a new connection), or the already opened connection (and you just use this one) but not both.

Comment: So in effect you want to know whether the imported mysqli object has a valid connection opened. Makes sense but still I fail to see why do you need the password. As of the connection checking, there is http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php which should be enough.

Comment: @YouCommonSense I want the sign-in information cause my class has some functions such as `dbexist` `tableexist` which creates a new connection with the login details. Just for safety so it does not error out and the functions will be useless, if I want to use those functions then I cant use the import function

Comment: You're doing something weird. Please learn the KISS principle and avoid complications in your code. There is ABSOLUTELY no point in creating a new connection to test whether a table exists.  Yet it can do some harm. What errors you are talking about? Why creating a new connection will prevent them?

Comment: I've had this weird error that when I try switching database from current selected it outputs an error. So thats why I am creating a new connection which does not specify database (`new mysqli('locahost', 'root', '[password]') `)

Comment: The only way I made the errors go away was to create a new connection which did not specify the database name as the above example

Comment: 1. you don't have to switch databases to see whether a database exists. SHOW DATABASES LIKE db_name query is enough. 2. Even with an error, you can always catch it. Anyway, let me suggest you to google for any task, before trying to solve yourself.

Comment: Thanks @YourCommonSense

Comment: wait, you cannot use a prepared statement with SHOW DATABASES query. Query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA instead.